# How to set modifying color of the image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a small web page.

I need to create the logo while dynamically changing the color of the image.

I need something like [**this**](http://nicolaisi.github.io/tancolor/)

I have got source from w3schools, but it doesn't seem useful to me.

I want to set the change of color dynamically for an infinite time.

Can anyone give a simple example?

Thanks.

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: So you want to keep changing the color for infinite time from red to yellow? Or use all colors of the rainbow?

Comment: all possible color... thanks .. here in my code only set css right.. So i need to set image ..

Comment: the website you linked, I saw, do you want exactly like that? edit image colors? if so, then you have to use `canvas` for that

Comment: `animation-iteration-count: infinite`?

Comment: It is not exact same.. I posted for sample... how can i change the color dynamically?.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rpuv1p8/1/)

You can use:

```
div {
   -webkit-animation example 10s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   animation: example 10s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color: red;}
    16%  {background-color: orange;}
    32%  {background-color: yellow;}
    48%  {background-color: green;}
    64% {background-color: blue;}
    80% {background-color: indigo;}
    100% {background-color: violet;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color: red;}
    16%  {background-color: orange;}
    32%  {background-color: yellow;}
    48%  {background-color: green;}
    64% {background-color: blue;}
    80% {background-color: indigo;}
    100% {background-color: violet;}
}
```

To make it even smoother you can end at red again, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rpuv1p8/2/)

Comment: What kind of image do you want to use?

Comment: Then it seems you need to use a plugin, like the one you mentioned in your post

Comment: I can have a look for you in a couple hours maybe. Check back in a few hours

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one , if you run this javascript your div background randomly changed in a period of time

```
var period = 1000;
setInterval(ChangeBG, period);   

function ChangeBG() {
    document.getElementById("divID").style.backgroundColor = 
        rgb(GetRandomValidNumber(), GetRandomValidNumber(), GetRandomValidNumber());
} 
function GetRandomValidNumber() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately CSS3 transitions don't work on `img` elements according the the W3C.

But there are workarounds for this limitation (e.g. ***using jQuery's `.animate()` method***).

A *possible* workaround for you is to have your images in multiple colors already created (*via some photo editing software like Photoshop*), and then implement them in `IMG` or `DIV` elements overlapping each other. 
Then, using javascript's `setInterval` method, you may **toggle the opacity** of those `div`s slowly to make each image gradually disappear and making the one underneath it become visible (and loop this process).

Something like the following (*assuming we have three images*):

```
   $(function(){
    var i = 3; //top most image's index (plus 1) | total number of images

    setInterval(function(){
        if(i === 1){
            $('.logoImage:not(:first-child)').each(function(){
                $(this).animate({
                opacity: 1.0
                },  400, "swing");
            });
            //ensure that the loop goes on
            i--;
            return false;
        }

        //reset i
        i = i > 1 ? i: 3;

        $('.logoImage').eq(--i).animate({
             opacity: 0.0
        }, 400, "swing");   

    }, 1000);
  });
```

[Check this out on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3d139m0/).

Comment: @aAhmad Baktash Hayeri: Not three images, I have to set only one image.. and background color of image only should change dynamically.. thanks..